# No drop information in build.complete webhook payload on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I created an Azure DevOps webhook for build.complete event and i'd like to get information about artifacts that have been published from the build but the resource.drop information is always null:

```
"resource": {
"uri": "vstfs:///Build/Build/10301",
"id": 10301,
"buildNumber": "cxcxzccxczxcxzcx_master_2018-12-17.3",
"url": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/_apis/build/Builds/10301",
"startTime": "2018-12-17T15:19:29.3762035Z",
"finishTime": "2018-12-17T15:22:01.4107196Z",
"reason": "batchedCI",
"status": "succeeded",
"drop": {},
"log": {},
```

I'm using the Publish Build Artifacts v.1 task to publish the artifact.  The artifact publish location is Azure Pipelines/TFS.  Is there something i should add to the build definition to get the information about the artifacts in the webhook payload?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?